# How to reorder a rhythmbox custom list by name/artist

Tags: rhythmbox

I want to reorder a list of song I have in Rhythmbox in a specific order (Right now by song name). I want to do this since when I import them to my IPod Shuffle they are very random (Same as the list). How can I order the songs by song name or author so it is easier for me to look for a specific one in Rhythmbox or to import them in a specific order to my IPod.